# Remove web panel access for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, bucket

I roughly know how to use IAM to grant fine level permissions to S3 buckets to individual users. However, I could not find anywhere how to block access to the bucket from AWS web account management panel.

[image: AWS Console for managing buckets]

The issue is - I would like to control read/writes to the bucket using my business logic layer. However, the panel provides CRUD access to the objects in the buckets (I could theoretically use the WORM locks to prevent accidental deletes - but preventing deletes completely is not what I want). There are actually dozens of business logic rules one may want to enforce that get broken with this sort of a panel, and I want to just disable the panel for the root user account.

Comment: *"However, the panel provides an open ended access to the buckets"* - no, the frontend calls the backend which properly respects any IAM and bucket policies that are set. Whatever you allow is accessible from the API and the Frontend, there is no difference.

Comment: @luk2302  Is there a way to block upload/delete of files by root user in the web panel? When I say open ended - I meant  it allows read/upload/delete which I want to do only through API with my business logic layer.

Comment: The root user can do anything, no point in restricting it. But the root user should not be used ever (other than for recovery purposes) and for every other user / role IAM can prevent any interaction, any upload, any delete, any read.

Comment: @luk2302  Okay - looks like I need to stop using the root account and get into the habit of IAM accounts for all operations except recovery as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disallow all web panel access to the buckets (and all access to root user, with or without the panel) using a policy like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "DenyAllButOneUser",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllButOneUser",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-uid/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-uid"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn-of-the-user-we-want-to-allow"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and ensuring that the IAM user with arn `arn-of-the-user-we-want-to-allow` has web login disabled.

Note that to regain accidentally lost access (for example if we delete the IAM user with access), we need to just "delete" the policy attached to the bucket using the root user account.